# How can I test (Minitest) that a (Rails) view contains a <td> element with a certain text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

When I simply use

`assert_select td, "test"`

it seems that it expects the first of the found td-elements to have the value test.

So I tried to first select all of them in an array, and then assume that the array
contains the expected value:

```
assert_select 'td' do |elements|
  assert elements.include?("test")
end
```

But this also doesn't work for me, as it is always green. I am not really sure which parts of Rails and Ruby are available in the test so this last idea was just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Your assert just asserts that the page contains any td element with the text test. If you want to check a certain element, you should specifiy it using a normal css selector. For instance by adding a class to the td and check it like this: `assert_select "td.your_class", "test"`

Comment: That's what I want to do: See if there is any td element on the page that contains the text "test". But the way I understand it, in my first example I test if the first td-element that is found contains "test".

Comment: Sorry you are correct, you need to point to the exact td to be able to test the content. Maybe you can do it with a loop, but I think that is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229544/assert-select-at-a-html-table-entry-in-rails

Comment: I tried the loop idea in the second approach that I show in my question. For some reason it is always passing. Can I call methods on elements in a test and make assertions on what it returns?

Comment: You could also select the table and then assert that it contains the string 'test' if you don't care in which cell it's present.

Comment: That is a good idea, I will try that! Thank you. Any ideas why my second approach won't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
assert_select 'td', /test/
```

it seems your td in not contains test only. // will work because it will match rather then comparing exact values.